# VIM Markdown folding: sections collapse subsections collapse subsubsection

Tags: vim, markdown, folding

Still really new to vim, I have the following question: having installed [this](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding) vim plugin, how to enable that a fold of, e.g, a section collapses all sub-sections? I don't have to stick to the referenced plugin, any other will do as well.

The current status, for example, is (I'm trying to visualize how my vim looks like):

```
# Section 1 [4 lines]------------------....
## SubSection 1 [3 lines]--------------....
## SubSection 2 [10 lines]-------------....
# Section 2 [5 lines]------------------....
## SubSection 1 [5 lines]--------------....
```

What I would like to get in addition is:

```
# Section 1 [19 lines]------------------....
# Section 2 [11 lines]------------------....
```

Unfolding this state results again in the first example.

Best, /nm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered by the documentation, see `:help markdown-folding-configuration`. Put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
let g:markdown_fold_style = 'nested'
```

Comment: BTW, `:help markdown-folding-configuration` doesn't give any result within my setup. I installed [this](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding) plugin via pathogen. Remember, I'm a vim-newbei :)

Comment: You need to execute `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` after installing a plugin (unless you use some plugin managers or Vimballs).

Comment: Nested is should be the default behaviour in Vim 9